# Matching an array mixed with text and numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, match

I am sorting an array mixed with numbers and a string in order, I want to return the array ignoring the single text string in it. this is my code.

```
function mySort(my_sort) {
return my_sort.sort(
  function(a, b){
    return a-b
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you please give example array and expected output?

Comment: add the array example of what you are talking about

Comment: ```let  my_sort =  [90, 45, 66, 'bye', 100.5] ;```

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Sorry for an incomplete que. My expected output should return ``` [90, 45, 66, 100.5] ;```

Comment: That's not a sort, that's a filter.

Answer (score 3):

You can first use `filter()` and `typeof` to remove all variables whose type is not number. I don't think you need `sort()`.

```js
let my_sort = [90, 45, 66, 'bye', 100.5] ;
const res = my_sort.filter(x => typeof x === "number")

console.log(res)
```

**Note**: In the question you are using sort directly on the argument which will modify the original array. Whenever you want to return new sorted array make sure to copy it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do `with` regex pattern `/[a-z]/ig`.if number is string format that means within quotes `'90'` its also number.It remove only `contain alphabets`

**Updated :** with odd sorting

```js
var remove = (my_sort) => my_sort.filter(a =>  !(/[a-z]/ig.test(a))).sort((a,b)=> (parseFloat(b)%2)-(parseFloat(a)%2))

console.log(remove(['90', 45, 66, 'bye', 100.5])) //number with quotes
console.log(remove(['90t', 45, 66, 'bye', 100.5])) //number contain string

console.log(remove(['6', 5, 6, '1', 100.5])) //odd sort
```

Comment: Your code will pass strings containing symbols. May be use `/[^0-9]/ig`

Comment: No,@MaheerAli see the last argument `100.5` is also affect.And `combine with symbol`  maximum not possible

Comment: I am back with one more clarification; what if I want to sort my_sort array such that odd numbers come first and even numbers come last?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the string, you can do a [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and use [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to check if element is number or not

```js
function mySort(my_sort) {
  return my_sort.filter(n => !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n))
    .sort((a, b) => a - b);
}

let result = mySort([90, 45, 66, 'bye', 100.5]);

console.log(result);
```

If you don't want to sort the numbers, you can just `filter`.

```js
function mySort(my_sort) {
  return my_sort.filter(n => !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n))
}

let result = mySort([90, 45, 66, 'bye', 100.5]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `Number` and `isNaN` both ways will have some problems. Both will pass strings like `'2'`. Secondly `filter(Number);` will remove `0` from array which is a number. Thirdly `isNaN` will pass empty string `''`

Comment: True. I updated the answer. But I think "2" should be accepted. I don't think because of eventhough on it string, it is still technically a number.